# Outlook Email Setup for JavaMail API

Tags: java, email, outlook

I having headache in setting up the outlook mail to JavaMail, I had followed the instructions from [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/apanicker/entry/java_code_for_smtp_server) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
          props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");

          try
          {
          Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
              }
            };

          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

          MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          msg.setText("Hey, this is the testing email.");
          msg.setSubject("Testing");
          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
          msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("example@gmail.com"));
          Transport.send(msg);

          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

And I keep getting the errors:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp-mail.outlook.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
```

I had searching around google and stackoverflow, I guess it is a MUST to use SSL instead of TLS because outlook doesn't accept TLS or else the connection will be close by remote host, but the solutions I found from Internet didn't work out. What am I missed in order to send my testing mail successfully?

I am total new to mail API, any advises or helps will be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have a email account from microsoft I registered similar to 'xxxx@outlook.com'

Comment: Oh my god, I finally solve it, when I login to my email in outlook.live.com, I saw a message mail from outlook team, saying that to continue sending messages, please sign in and validate my account. to helps us stop automated programs from sending junk email. After I validate my email, oh my god

Comment: interesting. never seen before.

Comment: anyway thanks for you guys effort and everything, be sure to check back the sender mail box next time haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the SocketFactory parameters like this, and enjoy sending emails.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

I didn't find this parameters necessary on the documentation.

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Comment: damn. 12 seconds ;-)

Comment: please refer my question comment, thanks for your effort! appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Please retry without these props:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
```

I do not have to set them for office365. outlook.com should be similiar

Comment: please refer my question comment, thanks for your effort! appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is worked for me

```
    Properties props = null;
    if (props == null) {
        props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", User);
        props.put("mail.smtp.pwd", Pwd);
    }
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(User));
    if (Objet != null) {
        msg.setSubject(Objet);

    }
    msg.setText(Content);
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailId));
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, User, Pwd);
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    System.out.println("Mail sent successfully at " + emailId);
    transport.close();
}
```